# iPhone backup & restore does not restore our app's data on rare occasions

Tags: iphone, itunes

We have an iPhone app with several thousand users, and we've had one or two users saying that after a full backup & restore procedure within iTunes, the data for our app was lost.

All the data (photos & SQLite DB) are stored in the documents area of the app. I've tested this thoroughly with our devices and it works absolutely fine.

Can anyone think of a reason for this, or has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Maybe those few users have jailbroken devices?

Comment: Hmm... interesting! I'll check with them.

Comment: It would appear that the users are __not__ on jail-broken devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem too - sometimes iTunes goes berserk and deletes data. Most apps are not important enough for people to complain, but if yours is you will hear about it. As it seems, you do.

My theory is that something goes wrong in iTunes and it uninstalls the app deleting the data, and then reinstalls it back - fresh and minty.

One thing I can suggest is storing data in both Keychain and Documents folder, and looking in both of these places. When an app is uninstalled the keychain is NOT cleaned up, at least not right away. However when backup is restored to a different device keychain is not carried along, so Documents is still a must.

The other option is to encourage online backup with user's permission. Of course you need to control access so that's a bit of a bother.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it's most probably iTunes going berserk every now and then! I'll just put it down to that and hope Apple continue to improve the backup and restore feature!

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly popular iPhone game, and every once in a while I'll hear from a user who has lost their data during a sync or backup just like this.

I've decided that iTunes syncing is just to volatile to rely on in the future. For my game, I've included an option for users to unlock the whole game all at once, so that it isn't as bad when they lose all their data. In future games and apps I'll be storing all user data in the cloud, which has a ton of benefits, and it'll fix/skip the whole iTunes sync issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree, I think that it's the iTunes backup process that can, on a rare occasion, lose an apps data.

Answer (score -1):

If the backup is where it belongs (in the MobileSync folder) there should be a button "Restore from iPhone Backup" on the Summary page when you click on the iPhone's name in iTunes. You need the latest version of iTunes installed.

If iOS needs to be restored also restore it with the Restore iPhone button; when the restore is done it will restore any valid backups that are in the MobileSync folder.